# Configure gitolite to exclude emails about certain branches

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a server using gitolite with lots of repositories. Right now, it sends an email to a mailing list after every commit. However, there are lots of these emails that really don't need to be generated. For example, we don't need to see if a branch was deleted, or if the branch is `*-signedoff` (we sign off branches before pushing to master). I'm trying to figure out if gitolite has a way of using a regex to have specific rules, but I can't find anything in the documentation or anyone else on the web who seems to be doing something similar.

Currently, the top level config looks like this:

```
repo @all
  config hooks.envelopesender = abc@xyz.com
  config hooks.emailprefix    = '[%GL_REPO] '
  config hooks.mailinglist    = abc-commits@xyz.com
  config hooks.emailmaxline   = 10000
  RW+>   = @admins  # Inherited to all repos
  RW>>   = @core  # Inherited to all repos
```

Is it possible to have per-commit rules in gitolite? Would I need to do something with a `post-receive` git hook?